# 1080p is missing from YouTube app on Android TV box

Tags: youtube, android-tv

I am using Android 4.4.2 which came preloaded on the Android TV box. It is capable of playing 1080p videos on it, and I can see them on my big TV too which is also 1080p TV. But when I use YouTube App from Google in Android TV Box, there is no 1080p option to play the YouTube videos in 1080p, the max option there is 720p.

My box is set to 1080p 60 Hz, TV is set to 1080p 16:9.

I have tried other methods I found on the internet, like reinstalling the YouTube app, clearing app data, rebooting various times, changing prop value to 4.4.2 Android which already is 4.4.2.

But still no luck, so how can I view YouTube videos in 1080p?

Answer (score 1):

This is the behavior of the YouTube app, it won't allow you to watch 1080p with HDMI plugged in.

There is an Xposed module for this (http://repo.xposed.info/module/uk.co.villainrom.pulser.youtubeallowfullscreenhdmi) if you are willing to root your device. Otherwise, use another YouTube app.